# Django Import Export, update record

Tags: django-import-export

I noticed that whenever I import the same set of CSV my records are duplicated even if I have skip_unchanged=True. Ideally, I wanted is if the CSV gets imported again it should not import the same records and prevent duplicate but it should update if there are changes to it.

I have this configuration in my resource file

```
bill_date = fields.Field(
    attribute="bill_date", column_name="date", widget=widgets.DateWidget()
)
```

then `import_id_fields = ("account_number",)`

I also tried printing the original and instance from the skip_row method but I get this in the logs,

`print(f"{getattr(original, "bill_date")} - {getattr(instance, "bill_date")}")`

`RESULT: None - 2021-06-07`

**UPDATE**

Fixed my issue, I mistakenly added `get_instance = False` during one of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine.  What you need to do is to ensure that `account_number` is included in the csv feed, and that it can uniquely identify a record in the table you are importing into.

Then, when the import occurs, the logic tries to load the existing record using `account_number` and will update the row if it is present, otherwise it creates a new row.

This is documented [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html), and you can debug the [`get_or_init_instance()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/89e52409787b36ea1f03e8eab2bfa68dc58e8a63/import_export/resources.py#L337) method if it is not working.

If `skip_unchanged` is true, then the logic will compare each field declared in your `fields` list, and will not update if there are no changes between the stored data and the imported data.

Comment: does it need to have a unique constraint? Also is it possible to use FK as the import_id_fields? The structure of my models is I have a bill that contains customer information then on my before_import_row, I do get_or_create on the customer information.

Comment: Also I don't get the desired behavior, I even cleared the data to make sure the account number is create on the first import but on the second import I still see duplicate records

Comment: I'm confused why this is not working on my end. Perhaps because I have before_import_row where I insert columns to my rows?

Comment: best thing to do (if you haven't already) is set up a debugger (I use PyCharm) and step through - you will be able to see exactly what is going on.  Sorry I can't be more help.